# What kind of data structure is an enum variable?

Tags: java, ruby, data-structures, token, symbols

Such as from the Java docs:

```
public enum Day {
  MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}
```

In Ruby, I believe these would be `Symbols`.  From the Ruby-Doc: "`Symbol` objects represent names and some `Strings` inside the Ruby interpreter".  What are these in Java and how does the compiler treat them?  As a `Token` or a Reference Literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are constant instances of the `enum` class, check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) and the actual [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Enum.java) if you are interested. So if you have this:

```
public enum Weekday
{
   MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}
```

it will internally be translated to:

```
class Weekday extends Enum
{
  public static final Weekday MONDAY  = new Weekday( "MONDAY",   0 );
  public static final Weekday TUESDAY = new Weekday( "TUESDAY ", 1 );
  // more constants

  private Weekday( String s, int i )
  {
    super( s, i );
  }

  // more methods
}
```

(Example from [here](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/javainsel9/javainsel_09_004.htm#mj2f6d324dfd3b9293fe6312045c460ad3), sorry it is not an english resource)

Answer (score 2):

`MONDAY` is an instance of `Enum<Day>`, a static final field of the class `Day`. Each Enum<Day> contains a single field 'String name'.  You can do:

```
 Enum<Day> x = Day.MONDAY;
```

Instances of `enum`s can be used in `switch` statements, they are a typed replacement for strings in some cases.

Enums are also often used to thread-safely create singletons:

```
enum MySingleton{
    INSTANCE;

    void instanceMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

enum in java are objects of class `enum` as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) and they are complete objects in java

meaning they can have instance and class methods

you can find in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html),[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that is a `generic object`... can be predefined or of type `Object`

you can read more about `Generics` in java to get familiar with it

Comment: I realize that an enum object is of the `Enum` class, but what are `MONDAY` or `TUESDAY`?  Is it a specific kind of reference literal like `null`?

Comment: i'm not sure but i think it's an `Object` the root of all classes in java :D

Comment: So I was forgetting that Java looks at inheritance rather that using duck typing like Ruby because I'm smart like that.  So, the Java interpreter already knows to treat those as `Objects`, rather than having to have a `Symbol` object to delegate how to handle something that isn't explicitly declared as a variable or method etc...?

Comment: bravo :D,this is how exactly i think it's doing... never needed to look into something like that. thanks for giving me the chance :D